# Is it possible to change (html and body) background color using semantic-ui

Tags: node.js, ejs, semantic-ui

When my ejs file is linked to a semantic ui, the second .css link doesn't work. Is it possible to change `html` and `body` background color using semantic-ui?

I linked these two css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
```

In homepage.css, when I type `html {background-color:pink}` this doesn't have any effect. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried `html {background-color:pink !important}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what your asking for but could be a workaround.

If you were to edit `site.variables` which is usally located at: `semantic/src/site/globals/site.variables`

And add an entry `@pageBackground: #5CDB95;` and change the `#5CDB95` to a colour of your choice, that will then be the default background colour of all pages where you include semantic ui.

After your entry dont forget to run `gulp build-css`

Hope this is of some help... Not sure why your css isnt overriding sematic ui, I know it sounds stupid but check you have included the `<html>` tags in your file.